# TRAVIS CI: `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

All the answers that I've found about this problem are related to the OS itself. This problem is occurring in Travis CI. This is my code:

```
# .travis.yml
language: ruby
cache: bundler
rvm:
- 2.5.3
services:
- postgresql
before_script:
- psql -c 'create database makerspacerepo;' -U postgres
- openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout certs/saml.key -out certs/saml.crt -days 1 -nodes -subj "/C=CA/ST=Ontario/L=Ottawa/O=uOttawa/OU=Richard L'Abbé Makerspace/CN=makerepo.com/emailAddress=travis-ci@makerepo.com"
jobs:
  include:
  - stage: test
    name: Test
    script:
    - bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake test RAILS_ENV=test
  - stage: deploy
    name: Deploy
    script:
    - openssl aes-256-cbc -k $DEPLOY_KEY -d -a -in config/deploy_id_rsa_enc_travis -out config/deploy_id_rsa
    - chmod 600 config/deploy_id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add config/deploy_id_rsa
    - bundle exec cap staging deploy
stages:
- name: test
- name: deploy
  if: branch = staging
```

I was able to build successfully and suddenly it started to give me this error:

```
$ bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 --deployment
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
The command "eval bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 --deployment " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
```

I have tried to specify a dist (`dist: trusty` and `dist: xenial`). I've tried to also comment `cache: bundler`. No success so far.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to .travis.yml to get Travis CI to work.

```
dist: trusty
```

Their default version of Ubuntu is now Xenial.  I think that it has a version of ruby gems that isn't compatible for some reason???

The following question could be the same as yours?

[Travis-CI is giving me an error when I am trying to build my site. What is wrong if the bundler matches with the gemfile.lock file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847081/travis-ci-is-giving-me-an-error-when-i-am-trying-to-build-my-site-what-is-wrong)