# Travis-CI is giving me an error when I am trying to build my site. What is wrong if the bundler matches with the gemfile.lock file?

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, travis-ci, bundler

I am getting this error when I am trying to build my site in Travis-CI. The bundler version matches the Bundled_With version in the Gemlock file. I'm not sure if I am updating Git correctly. I am building a Jekyll site from a Lynda tutorial.

$ bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 --deployment

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
4: from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

3: from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'

2: from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

1: from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
```

/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

The command "eval bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 --deployment " failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to .travis.yml to get Travis CI to work.

```
dist: trusty
```

Their default version of Ubuntu is now Xenial.  I think that it has a version of ruby gems that isn't compatible for some reason???

The following question could be the same as yours?

[TRAVIS CI: `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263906/travis-ci-find-spec-for-exe-cant-find-gem-bundler-0-a-with-executable)